# Socket server loop and waiting serial command in python?

Tags: python, sockets

Problem with socket server while loop and waiting serial command in python.

I have server code in python like this:

```
import serial
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('', 9000))
sock.listen(1)
print "Listening on TCP 9000"
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1)
print "Connected at: /dev/ttyUSB0"
while(1):
    print "Waiting For Connection..."

    connection, addr = sock.accept() #PROBLEM HERE

    # IF THERE IS NOT CLIENT, PROGRAM CAN NOTO CONTINUE TO NEXT LINE
    print "Connected"

    #SO I CAN NOT CHECK THE COMMAND FROM SERIAL IN THE SAME TIME
    dataFromSerial = ser.readline()
    if dataFromSerial == "ON":
        #SET LED ON
```

Help me please...
Thanks...

Comment: What is the problem ? Getting some exception?? Please explain.

Comment: The problem is: when there is no client, program will waiting in code:
   connection, addrs = sock.accept()

Answer (score 0):

Set the listening socket nonblocking and catch socket timeouts (which apparently can also manifest themselves as `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` errors):

```
import errno
sock.setblocking(False)  # just once, probably right after listen()
try:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    # conn accepted
except socket.error as e:
    if e.errno not in (errno.EAGAIN, errno.EWOULDBLOCK):
        raise  # some sort of error we don't recognize; re-raise
    pass  # no connections were pending
```

Comment: @icktoofay: For the time there are no connections, this will cause exceptions continuously (whih will be obviously caught), but wont it waste precious CPU cycles ?

Comment: @GodMan: If this is all that was happening in the loop, yes, you’d just be wasting cycles polling rather than blocking. However, it’s not the only thing in the loop: they want to check if there’s an incoming connection, and then interact with the serial port. Presumably if there were no incoming connections they’d be looping and dealing with the serial port anyway; it’s just that they *additionally* want to deal with a connection if and only if one is available at the beginning of the loop, and if that’s the goal, this seems to be a reasonably efficient way to do it.

Comment: @icktoofay: I have error: [Error 11] Resource temporarily unavailable. Why?

Comment: @JackyD.Syam: It looks like I was trying to catch the wrong kind of exception. (`socket.timeout` is only raised if the timeout is *nonzero* and the timeout has been hit; if the timeout is zero, we have to probe a general `socket.error`.) Try again now.

Comment: @icktoofay: how if I want to set timeout is nonzero? I did write code:    socket.settimeout(5)   and I try this code:    socket.setdefaulttimeout(5). But still not working (error)

Comment: @JackyD.Syam: If you want to catch a non-zero timeout, you should just be able to catch `socket.timeout`. In that case, make sure you *replace* `sock.setblocking(False)` with `sock.settimeout(5)`; a non-blocking socket with a timeout sounds like an opportunity for trouble (although I wouldn’t be surprised if Python made them override eachother here).

Comment: There is not error now. Now I can run server, but when I connect from client, server not available, maybe this method impossible?

Comment: @JackyD.Syam: I just tried the code in my answer and it works just fine. Furthermore, the code in the previous revision of my answer, after replacing `sock.setblocking(False)` with `sock.settimeout(5)`, also works. I’m not sure why it’s not working for you.